# WebResource.axd and ScriptResource.axd weird behaviour

Tags: ajax.net, webresource.axd, scriptresource.axd

I am building a website, to be used primarily in my internal network. I am facing a very frustrating problem with AJAX .NET. To explain the problem, first let me detail out my environment.

I am developing in Visual Studio .NET 2010, targeting .NET framework 4.0.
My staging server is a win7 utlimate machine having the complete configuration of IIS 7 installed.
I am using MySql Server 5.1 as my database server
The staging server has the required MySQL connectors installed 
I am using the Membership class to authenticate and authorize my users. With mysql, I am following this article to accomplish this : http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/mysqlmembershipprovider.aspx
The staging server is using AVG antivirus along with windows firewall.
I am using the toolKitScriptManager on all my pages.

The application works perfectly fine in visual studio. Also, when deployed on the staging server, it works fine on any browser on the staging server as well. The website also works fine on other machines inside my network, when I access it by tying the ip adderess:port of the server. Now the problem is that after some time of usage the website just hangs. As in it says page loading for a long time before eventually timing out. This issue goes away if I clear the cache and restart the browser but reappears after some time. This issue is witnessed only on the networked machines. We have never encountered it on the web browsers of the staging server.

I have succeeded in a controlled reproroduction of the issue. Whenever the page loads and I hit refresh on the page, the problem appears. If I go back and try to access the same page by clicking the page link, it works. But if I hit refresh, the page just keeps on saying loading and eventually times out.

I have examined the network by using the google chrome developer toolbar and firebug and I found that whenever the problem occurs, some webresource.axd and scriptresource.axd files show up as "pending".

After spending more then 15 days, researching google to combat this issue, I have unsuccessfully tried the following remedies :

Thinking it might have something to do with concurrent connection limit of IIS7 on win 7, I tested it with minimal load, that is just one user accessing the site. I also monitored the IIS worker processes to see if the requests are queeued up there, but I see no pending requests, The problem is still there. 
Thinking it might have something to do with firewall blockage, I disabled the firewall on my staging server. The problem is still there.
Thinking it has something to do with my web.config settings, I checked my web.config a thousand times for mistakes, but all sections are intact. Please see the web.config file at the end of this listings for any signs of problem
Your kind suggestions please.

My web.config follows :

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
        <configSections>
                <sectionGroup name="system.web.extensions" type="System.Web.Configuration.SystemWebExtensionsSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35">
                        <sectionGroup name="scripting" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35">
                                <sectionGroup name="webServices" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingWebServicesSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35">
                                </sectionGroup>
                        </sectionGroup>
                </sectionGroup>
        </configSections>
        <connectionStrings>
                <add name="ConnString" connectionString="Database=scsbackend;Data Source=localhost;User Id=xxxxx;Password=xxxx"/>
        </connectionStrings>
        <system.web>
                <sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="90000"></sessionState>
                <authorization>
                        <allow roles="Admin"/>
                        <allow roles="Tellecaller"/>
                        <deny users="?"/>
                </authorization>
                <authentication mode="Forms"/>
                <roleManager defaultProvider="MySqlRoleProvider" enabled="true" cacheRolesInCookie="true" cookieName=".ASPROLES" cookieTimeout="90000" cookiePath="/" cookieRequireSSL="false" cookieSlidingExpiration="true" cookieProtection="All">
                        <providers>
                                <clear/>
                                <add name="MySqlRoleProvider" type="Andri.Web.MySqlRoleProvider" connectionStringName="ConnString" applicationName="mysqlmembership" writeExceptionsToEventLog="true"/>
                        </providers>
                </roleManager>
                <membership defaultProvider="MySqlMembershipProvider" userIsOnlineTimeWindow="15">
                        <providers>
                                <clear/>
                                <add name="MySqlMembershipProvider" type="Andri.Web.MySqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="ConnString" applicationName="mysqlmembership" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true" requiresUniqueEmail="true" passwordFormat="Hashed" writeExceptionsToEventLog="true"/>
                        </providers>
                </membership>
                <pages validateRequest="false">
                        <controls>
                                <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
                        </controls>
                        <tagMapping>
                                <add tagType="System.Web.UI.WebControls.CompareValidator" mappedTagType="Sample.Web.UI.Compatibility.CompareValidator, Validators, Version=1.0.0.0"/>
                                <add tagType="System.Web.UI.WebControls.CustomValidator" mappedTagType="Sample.Web.UI.Compatibility.CustomValidator, Validators, Version=1.0.0.0"/>
                                <add tagType="System.Web.UI.WebControls.RangeValidator" mappedTagType="Sample.Web.UI.Compatibility.RangeValidator, Validators, Version=1.0.0.0"/>
                                <add tagType="System.Web.UI.WebControls.RegularExpressionValidator" mappedTagType="Sample.Web.UI.Compatibility.RegularExpressionValidator, Validators, Version=1.0.0.0"/>
                                <add tagType="System.Web.UI.WebControls.RequiredFieldValidator" mappedTagType="Sample.Web.UI.Compatibility.RequiredFieldValidator, Validators, Version=1.0.0.0"/>
                                <add tagType="System.Web.UI.WebControls.ValidationSummary" mappedTagType="Sample.Web.UI.Compatibility.ValidationSummary, Validators, Version=1.0.0.0"/>
                        </tagMapping>
                </pages>
                <!--
          Set compilation debug="true" to insert debugging
          symbols into the compiled page. Because this
          affects performance, set this value to true only
          during development.
    -->
                <compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.0">
                        <assemblies>
                                <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
                                <add assembly="MySql.Data, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=C5687FC88969C44D"/>
                                <add assembly="System.Transactions, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
                                <add assembly="System.Configuration.Install, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
                                <add assembly="System.Design, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
                                <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
                                <add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
                                <add assembly="Accessibility, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
                                <add assembly="System.Runtime.Remoting, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
                                <add assembly="System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
                                <add assembly="Accessibility, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
                                <add assembly="System.Web.ApplicationServices, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
                                <add assembly="System.ServiceModel.Activation, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
                                <add assembly="System.Runtime.Serialization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
                                <add assembly="System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
                                <add assembly="System.Configuration, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
                                <add assembly="System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
                                <add assembly="System.Xml, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
                                <add assembly="System.Web.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
                                <add assembly="System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
                                <add assembly="System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
                                <add assembly="System.Data.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
                                <add assembly="System.Drawing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
                                <add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
                                <add assembly="System.ServiceModel.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
                                <add assembly="System.Data.Services.Client, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
                                <add assembly="System.Data.Services.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
                                <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
                                <add assembly="System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/></assemblies>
                </compilation>
                <httpHandlers>
                        <remove verb="*" path="*.asmx"/>
                        <add verb="*" path="*.asmx" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
                </httpHandlers>
                <httpModules>
                        <add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
                </httpModules>
        </system.web>
        <location path="Default.aspx">
                <system.web>
                        <authorization>
                                <allow roles="Admin"/>
                                <allow roles="Tellecaller"/>
                        </authorization>
                </system.web>
        </location>
        <location path="SCS_Webcontrol.aspx">
                <system.web>
                        <authorization>
                                <allow roles="Admin"/>
                                <allow roles="Tellecaller"/>
                        </authorization>
                </system.web>
        </location>
        <location path="M/scs.aspx">
                <system.web>
                        <authorization>
                                <allow roles="Admin"/>
                                <deny roles="Tellecaller"/>
                        </authorization>
                </system.web>
        </location>
        <location path="SCS_Reports.aspx">
                <system.web>
                        <authorization>
                                <allow roles="Admin"/>
                                <deny roles="Tellecaller"/>
                        </authorization>
                </system.web>
        </location>
        <location path="Webcontrol_WebService.asmx">
                <system.web>
                        <authorization>
                                <allow users="?"></allow>
                        </authorization>
                </system.web>
        </location>
        <system.webServer>
                <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
                <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
                        <add name="ScriptModule" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
                </modules>
                <handlers>
                        <remove name="WebServiceHandlerFactory-ISAPI-2.0"/>
                        <add name="ScriptHandlerFactory" verb="*" path="*.asmx" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
                        <add name="ScriptResource" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
                </handlers>
        </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution/answer to this problem? I am experiencing the same issue now with some of my users getting "pending" for request to WebResources.axd. However, when clearing the browser cache the problem disappears, but in the debug console I can see that the WebResource.axd having the problem is "interpreted as script but transferred with MIME type text/plain", maybe that leads to some problem. Also, the resource file is empty...